# Is "content" a valid javascript variable name?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using prototype and have the following javascript:

```
function displayDefinition(term){
var term_id = term.gsub(/[ '’]/,"_");    
$(term_id).observe('click', function() {
new Ajax.Request('/terms/display_definition', 
  {parameters: { 
      term: term, 
  }}) 
})   
}
```

I am having very strange behavior when the term is the string "content".  Is this an invalid javascript variable name?  And if so, what is the best way to get around it?

Comment: Maybe you could try to describe this *strange behavior*? And yes, `content`, is a perfectly valid variable name in javascript.

Comment: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: If you're on firefox, then you might be getting this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content by mistake.

Comment: "Is this an invalid javascript variable name?" No, it isn't. The same way that "window" and "document" are also perfectly valid variable names, so valid in fact they are used by the browser! By which I mean: sure, you can use them if you want to, but you will obscure the other variables if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's because there's already another element with the id `content` in the document. It isn't allowed to have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. Use ids that aren't already being used for something else.

Comment: the trailing coma on "term: term," is going to bite you on some browsers as well.